# XmlReader: is there a way of finding the first child, and next sibling?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, xmlreader

I am porting code that uses an XmlDocument. XmlNode has a FirstChild
and NextSibling property.  Using XmlReader, is there a way of parsing
until the first child, or the next sibling, given the xmlreader has parsed
to an arbitrary element in the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XmlRreader, you are working in other scheme. You always *are* at some *current* node, and you switch to next one. For the current node, you can ask `IsEmptyElement` (which says if the tag is of the form `<something attr=value/>`. If the element is empty, clearly you have no child items.

Consider the case when `IsEmptyElement` is false, now you have something like `<something> <maybechild/> </something>`. You can say `ReadStartElement`, which will move you to the next position. For the next position you check `IsStartElement`. If it's true, you have a child and you are at it. If not, you are at `</something>` and there are no children.

Some more documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9bfea29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Build an `XPathDocument` and create an `XPathNavigator` using `CreateNavigator`.  It has methods for (as the name implies) navgating XML.  The equivalent methods are `MoveToFirstChild` and `MoveToNext`.

Comment: THanks, Mark. I am using XmlReader to avoid memory and performance overhead.  I was thinking of using the depth property to determine child or sibling.